# ExpressJS export routes in external file not working for root path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I want to export my routes in external files.

Everything but the root route is working:

localhost/login -> "Login page"

localhost/ -> empty

**server.js:**

```
// SET UP =============
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 80;
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// CONFIG =============
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));

// ROUTES =============
var base = require("./routes/base");
app.use("/",base);

// LISTEN =============
app.listen(port);
console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
```

**base.js:**

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

//Home
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Home page')
})

//Login
router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Login page')
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: check console to see any error on root route

Comment: @noobcode No errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the route on `app.use('/', base)` instead just supply the router middleware directly to your express app and let the router within `base` handle the request.

`app.use(base)`

Comment: Seems obviously, but no, theres still no output on localhost/

Comment: @Waterfront, then you're omitting something from your setup because it works for me. I copied and pasted and worked no problem, just needed to change port from 80 to something other than that. Maybe thats your problem, change your port to 8080 and see if it works.

Comment: @Waterfront furthermore, this shouldn't even be a problem even with `app.use('/', base)` as it will work either as you have it now or the way I've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, okay I found my problem.

There is an empty **index.html** in my *./public* folder.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the root route with your /login route and only exporting the /login one because of that. If you want to keep all routes in one file I recommend doing something in you `base.js` file like:

```
module.exports = function(server){
    server.get('/', function(request, response){
        response.send('Home page.');
    });

    server.get('/login', function(request, response){
        response.send('Login page.');
    });
}
```

Then in the `server.js` file import the route using:

```
require('./routes/base.js')(app);
```

This immediately imports the routes and calls their functionality on the Express server you crated :)

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow, but it looks for me a bit messy. :)